# Variable parameters not accepting in @Url.ACtion()

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-4

I am Passing two variable parameters in `@Url.Action()`. But its not accepting the variable parameters but accepting constant values. My code is like this

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".print").click(function () {
        var id = $(#id).val();
        var dept = $(#dept ).val();
        var url = "@Html.Raw(@Url.Action("ActionResultname", "ControllerName", new {sid= id , sdept=dept }))";
        window.location.href = url;
    });
});
```

here `id` & `sid` is not accepting as a value , its taking as string . But if i pass like

```
var url = "@Html.Raw(@Url.Action("ActionResultname", "ControllerName", new {sid= 10, sdept=30}))";
```

Its accepting correctly as `sid=10` & `sdept=30`. Please help me how to pass a variable to the parameter.

Comment: Razor code is parsed on the server **before** its sent to the view. It does not get updated just because you define some javascript variables

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't pass JavaScript variable to `Url.Action` as it is execute on server side. further `Url.Action` function will render a string.

However, You can use generate url with static value and replace it with your input.

```
//Render Url with -1 and -2 value
var url = '@Url.Action("ActionResultname", "ControllerName", new { sid = -1, sdept= -2})'; 
url = url.replace(-1, id); //replace -1 with id
url = url.replace(-2, dept); //replace -2 with dept

window.location.href = url;
```

Comment: Hi @Satpal, Could this approach been used  to pass a Json object as one of the parameters?. If so could you expand on how, I'm been trying for hours now, and I always get the object initialize on the server but with null parameters.Thanks.

Comment: In fact trying to pass two integers is not working for me, the second one always is pass as false...any ideas of why?

Comment: @Juan, No, this approach is not useful when you want to pass JSON and It would be better if you post a new question that way lot more users can help you. You can also share link with me also

Comment: Apparently the reason why my second parameter is null, even when both parameters are integers, is because the separation between them is &amp; which for some reason is not working, if instead I created the url manually separating parameters with a simple & it works.

Answer (score 1):

In your case I would suggest just writing out the link you want as Razor code runs server-side so it won't get updated with the values you want. 
How about you change your code to:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".print").click(function () {
        var id = $(#id).val();
        var dept = $(#dept ).val();
        var url = "/ControllerName/ActionResultname?sid=" + id + "&sdept=" +dept;
        window.location.href = url;
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

This not possible you need to append the query through client side
try this

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".print").click(function () {
        var id = $('#id').val();
        var dept = $('#dept').val();
        var url = '@Url.Action("ActionResultname", "ControllerName")';
        url += "?sid= " + id + "&sdept=" + dept;
        window.location.href = url;
    });
});
```